How to remove y-outliers from x-y Scatter plot in Python?
I am plotting a dataframe, df, containing x and y in a scatter plot. Clearly, in many cases, for each x value, y-values may be scattered. I want to remove y outliers for each x. This is different from bulk outlier removal using IQRs.
Can anyone assist with the same?
I was not able to find any ready-made code for this. There are codes that remove outliers in bulk, not selectively for each x.

Would you mind marking the answer as correct if it helped you out?

Group DataFrame by the x column and then apply a function to remove outliers from each group:
def remove_outliers(group, column='y'):
    Q1 = group[column].quantile(0.25)
    Q3 = group[column].quantile(0.75)
    IQR = Q3 - Q1
    lower_bound = Q1 - 1.5 * IQR
    upper_bound = Q3 + 1.5 * IQR
    return group[(group[column] >= lower_bound) & (group[column] <= upper_bound)]
df = df.groupby('x').apply(remove_outliers).reset_index(drop=True)


Awesome! Very neat indeed. Thanks very much!
